Sailboat physics
I want to program a simulation of a sailing boat, but I ran into a problem with the physical law of lift and drag
$$F_D=\dfrac{C_D}{2} \rho \cdot A  \cdot V^2$$
$$F_L=\dfrac{C_L}{2} \rho \cdot A \cdot V^2$$
Everything is pretty good except $C_D$ (Coefficient drag) and $C_L$ (Coefficient lift)
I understood that it depends on the shape (sail or keel) and the angle of attack, but do I have to calculate it? Or should it be retrieved from a database for a real experience? If I have to get it, from where?

The physics of a sailboat are highly complex, involving interactions between wind, current, sail, direction of rudder, angle of mast and boom with many other factors including shape of hull and keel and even the weight of the crew and their position within the boat. If this is your first (or even second) computer simulation then I suggest you cut your teeth on some less ambitious.

Thank you for your advice، but I have to do a simulation of a sailing boat, even if it is not 100% correct. If you know something useful that I can see, please tell me about it.

If you are not worried about being able to generalise your simulation to other boats, then the simplest approach may be to collect some real-life data for a specific boat and then try to replicate its behaviour in your simulation.
